# c++: replace multiple index equality tests by a single function call

Tags: c++

In c++/c++11 what is the proper way to replace multiple comparison of the form:

```
if(isIndexToFind==index1 || isIndexToFind==index2 ...)
```

with something less messy of the form:

```
if(isIn(indexToFind,index1,index2,...))
```

For a varying number of parameters index1, index2, ... This code belongs to a numerical so I would like to have something nearly as efficient as the direct comparison.

Maybe it is interesting to add that index1, index2 are const static values thus maybe variadic template based solution could be of interest ?

Comment: The types involved in the comparison may be useful information. integer (signed/unsigned), char (signed/unsigned), etc.

Comment: @AndyG. Unsigned int seems good for me

Answer (score 3):

You can write something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

template <class T>
bool one_of( const T &value, std::initializer_list<T> lst )
{
    return std::any_of( lst.begin(), lst.end(), [&]( const T &x ) { return value == x; } );
}    

int main()
{
    std::cout << one_of( 1, { 2, 3, 1, 5 } ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << one_of( 4, { 2, 3, 1, 5 } ) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I like that !  To your opinion , what about performance of this solution ? I ask this, because as all indices are known before compiling I was thinking about solution based on template ?

Comment: @user1835313 It is linear depending on the number of items in the list.

Comment: But what about the list conversion ?

Comment: @user1835313 It depends on whether the objects are compound.

Answer (score 1):

You could use std::any_of.

```
v.push_back(index1);
v.push_back(index2);

if (std::any_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](int& index){return index==isIndexToFind;}))
```

If your really want to use the form you mention then a variadic template could also work. Something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
bool isIn(T indexToFind,T first_index) { return indexToFind==first_index; } 

template<typename T,typename ... Tail>
bool isIn(T indexToFind,T first_index, Tail... remaining_indices)
{
    if (indexToFind==first_index)
        return true;
    else
        return isIn(indexToFind,remaining_indices...);
}

const static int index1{23};
const static int index2{34};
const static int index3{88};
const static int index4{24};
const static int index5{21};

int main()
{
    bool found = isIn(621,index1,index2,index3,index4,index5);

    if (found) {
        std::cout << "Index was found\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Index was not found\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My point about template is that as index1, index2 , .. are known before compiling the function could be "hardcoded" for these values, is  it ?

Comment: Ah ok, I think I you mean to actually place these constants in the variadic template?

Comment: Yes I think it is this. My point is that it could be almost equivalent to th naive code but less ugly...

Comment: The variadic template shown would be no more or less efficient than the form if(isIndexToFind==index1 || isIndexToFind==index2 ...). In both cases the code stops evaluating once a true comparison is made. How exactly do you wish to call the function? With something like if(isIn(indexToFind,index1,index2,...)), correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since, all of the answers so far, are with linear search complexity (`arrays`, `vectors`, etc.), I propose the usage of `std::set` which has logarithmic complexity for look-ups. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
int main()
    {
    std::set<int> set{ 5, 6, 1, 2 };
    std::cout << (set.count(6) > 0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (set.count(3) > 0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: building the set is O(N log(N)) then you have a O(log(N)) lookup.  Vlad's answer could be optimized by the compiler be just O(N).

Comment: @NathanOliver If it is used for one time only check, yes, you are right, but, if the lookup is done several times, on the same object, than the `std::set` would be faster. In addition, since the OP stated, that that variable set, on which he needs to look-up on, are `static const`, which implies, that he could just create a single `std::set` instance with those variables, and keep searching on that. Which would be faster in the long-run.

Comment: Correct.  I was assuming this was a one and done situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to use an array as a kind of lookup table for something like this.

Let's assume your indices are `int`:

```
std::array<int, N> indicesTable{{index1, index2, ...}};
bool in = std::find(std::begin(indicesTable), std::end(indicesTable), isIndexToFind) != std::end(indicesTable);
if (in)
   // ...
```

### EDIT:

If you store your indices in sorted order, you can use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) pr [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) to perform a binary search on the lookup table:

```
auto iter = std::lower_bound(std::begin(indicesTable), std::end(indicesTable), isIndexToFind);
bool in = iter != std::end(indicesTable) && *iter == isIndexToFind;
if (in){
   // ...
```